# How to find which device is attached to a USB-serial port in Linux using C?

Tags: c

We are making a device and it has 8 serial ports. It runs on the Monta Vista Pro5 kernel. And we are working in C.

**Suppose:** A device gets attached to ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1 and ttyUSB2. The next device gets connected to ttyUSB3 and another to ttyUSB4. How can I know which device gets attached to which port ?? ie ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1 or so on. Is there a way to directly query the device and find which port it is attached to. Or, in C, open ttyUSB0, query it somehow and get some reply as to which device it is ??

**A rather complicated way:** do a stat of, say /dev/ttyUSB0. Get the device number. And search for this in /proc/bus/usb/devices and find the vendor id or something to identify the device.

**Or:** Is there some way to reserve ttyUSB0,ttyUSB1 and ttyUSB2 for one device, ttyUSB3 for another and so on when they are plugged in ? This way I will know which device is connected to which port.

Help please..... :)

Thanks in advance.
Nubin Stanley

Comment: Let me see if I got this right. What you are trying to do is match the /dev/ttyUSBx nodes to the /proc/bus/usb device on the host system? Or are you trying to identify a serial device that is conencted to a usbserial adapter?

Comment: stat'ing /dev/<whatever> will only get you the major and minor versions of the device. Those are not by any means connected to vendor/product/device ids.

Comment: So you have a device with some usbserial IC (e.g. from FTDI) and you need to identify it ? Have you set vendor/product ids and serial number in the usbserial chip ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use udev rules to create symbolic links just to your device:

(these rules go in /etc/udev/rules.d/-name.rules  -- look at your udev documentation

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="<vendorid>", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="mydev"
```

You have to specify your vendor id and/or product id for your device. Then those devices will be available at /dev/mydev in the above example.

You can also use various other parameters to create appropriate unique symbolic links for your use. Check udev man page.

Comment: What you suggested would help me to get a unique link to my device. But that is not what I want.

Comment: 3 random devices have been connected, and they occuppy ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1 and ttyUSB2.

Now the problem is, I don't know which devices is connected to which port.

I need a way to find out which device is connected to ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1 or ttyUSB2 :)

Comment: I have answered your question - "Is there some way to reserve ttyUSB0,ttyUSB1 and ttyUSB2 for one device, ttyUSB3 for another...". If you wanted to reserve device entries to one device, you need to know the details of that device. Ofcourse, if they are random devices, this won't help.

Comment: Oh Ok, now I got you. So using udev rules, I can basically tell the OS to attach Device0 with a particular <VendorId> to ttyUSB0 and so on ???

Comment: If that is the case, this should be the perfect solution. I know the devices I am connecting and hence their vendor ids.
So whenever I connect that device, it will get attached to that particular ttyUSB<x> ???
Let me look into the udev docs. And the example you gave, will making the same entry with my device vendor id, into that file, make it attach to a particular port ???

Comment: Only thing is you can keep off from using ttyUSB, and leave it to the kernel to manage. By using "SYMLINK+" or "NAME" you can create device names of your choice. Udev supports using several variables like "%n", "%b", the devpath etc. in naming your device. Naming like "ttyMyUSB%n" is much preferred.

Comment: Of course if you have multiple devices of the same vendor & model you need to also have a distinct serial number for each one in order to be able to tell them apart. Some time ago I bought a few webcams for a quick & dirty surveillance solution and they all had the same USB serial number...

Comment: @thkala-I just what to find out what device is attached to a particular port.

Comment: @rsmoorthy-so, the device might get attached to any of the ttyUSbs but I'll have a link to those devices with the names I have given, right ?
And "ttyMyUSB%n" is preferred in the sense ?? Like what is the "\n" required for ???

Comment: And also, there is no "-name.rules" file in "/etc/udev/rules.d/" for me. So should I just make one ?? And there is a'-' before "name.rules" right ?? :)

Comment: @rsmoorthy-It was '%n'... and not '\n'... and sorry for asking without properly reading the man page :)

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Got it fixed :)
@rsmoorthy : special thanks to you :)

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. Also, I actually had put in /etc/udev/rules.d/(number)-(yourname).rules, but had typed '<' and '>', so it became a tag and did not get displayed. It is preferable that the number is somewhere around 50 for user defined rules.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my code, based on Alex Robinson's, but without global "except":

```
import os
from os.path import join

def find_tty_usb(idVendor, idProduct):
    """find_tty_usb('067b', '2302') -> '/dev/ttyUSB0'"""
    # Note: if searching for a lot of pairs, it would be much faster to search
    # for the enitre lot at once instead of going over all the usb devices
    # each time.
    for dnbase in os.listdir('/sys/bus/usb/devices'):
        dn = join('/sys/bus/usb/devices', dnbase)
        if not os.path.exists(join(dn, 'idVendor')):
            continue
        idv = open(join(dn, 'idVendor')).read().strip()
        if idv != idVendor:
            continue
        idp = open(join(dn, 'idProduct')).read().strip()
        if idp != idProduct:
            continue
        for subdir in os.listdir(dn):
            if subdir.startswith(dnbase+':'):
                for subsubdir in os.listdir(join(dn, subdir)):
                    if subsubdir.startswith('ttyUSB'):
                        return join('/dev', subsubdir)
```

Answer (score 2):

This Python code seems to find the /dev/ttyUSB number for the given vendor ID and product ID. Not hard to translate it to C. Parsing the output from `hwinfo --usb` can do the trick, too. The regx is:

```
"\s\sVendor:\susb\s0x([0-9a-f]{4}).*?\s\sDevice:\susb\s0x([0-9a-f]{4}).*?\s\sDevice\sFile:\s/dev/ttyUSB([0-9]+)"
```

```
import  glob
import  os
import  re

def find_usb_tty(vendor_id = None, product_id = None) :
    tty_devs    = []

    for dn in glob.glob('/sys/bus/usb/devices/*') :
        try     :
            vid = int(open(os.path.join(dn, "idVendor" )).read().strip(), 16)
            pid = int(open(os.path.join(dn, "idProduct")).read().strip(), 16)
            if  ((vendor_id is None) or (vid == vendor_id)) and ((product_id is None) or (pid == product_id)) :
                dns = glob.glob(os.path.join(dn, os.path.basename(dn) + "*"))
                for sdn in dns :
                    for fn in glob.glob(os.path.join(sdn, "*")) :
                        if  re.search(r"\/ttyUSB[0-9]+$", fn) :
                            #tty_devs.append("/dev" + os.path.basename(fn))
                            tty_devs.append(os.path.join("/dev", os.path.basename(fn)))
                        pass
                    pass
                pass
            pass
        except ( ValueError, TypeError, AttributeError, OSError, IOError ) :
            pass
        pass

    return tty_devs

print find_usb_tty()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is would be to use [`libusb`](http://www.libusb.org/), but if that doesn't give you enough information about your devices (which it may not), then you'll have to use the `/proc` filesystem which the kernel makes available, specifically `/proc/bus/usb/`.

Have a read of [this information](http://tali.admingilde.org/linux-docbook/usb/ch07.htm) on `/proc/bus/usb`: in particular on `/proc/bus/usb/devices`. But as you say, this is all a bit hacky!

Comment: I am currently working on libusb. But then again, i don't know if it would give me any indication as to which port a device is connected to...... Suppose i query my device using libusb, i need to somehow find out 'x' in /dev/ttyUSB<x> so that i can know that the particular device is /dev/ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1 or so on :)